# Как правильнее: "ей", "в ней" или "на ней"?

Tags: грамотная-речь, предлоги

Контекст такой:

> Приятно любоваться водной гладью и лунным светом, отражённым **ей**.

По сути, логичнее выглядит **ей**, поскольку гладь отражает свет. Но ведь и сам свет отражается... Отражается **в** или **на**?

Comment: Лучше употребить в данном примере "отраженным ЕЮ".

Answer (score 2):

[гладь](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/es/102598/%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%8C), -и; ж.

1. Гладкая водная поверхность. *Морская гладь. Гладь озера, залива. Зеркальная гладь воды. **Рассекать носом водную гладь*** (о катере).

Водная гладь — это не просто ровная отражающая поверхность (как у зеркала). Это определенное (вещественное, материальное) **количество воды** (то есть масса воды), находящееся в спокойном состоянии (иначе бы рассечь ее было бы просто невозможно).

Отражаться (где? в чём? на чём?) — в воде, на глади (здесь вопросов нет).
Но со словосочетанием "водная гладь", считаю, могут использоваться оба предлога: **в** — внутри, в слое воды; **на** — на плоскости.

Примеры только с предлогом "в" (с предлогом "на" уже имеются).

Ф. Шиллер ("[Друзьям](https://wysotsky.com/0009/435.htm)", перевод Н. Чуковского):
*Но не в том ручье, который несся

После ливня, мутен, шумен, дик, —

**В ясной водной глади, в тихом плесе

Отразился солнца лик.***

*Ставни терема разверзлись, и набежавший ветерок задул свечу за свечой, а полная луна, проникнув мутным взором сквозь пустые глазницы окон, **отразилась в водной глади*** (Д. Гаврилов).
*Диск солнца уже давно отделился от линии горизонта и слепил глаза, **отражаясь в водной глади озера**, на берегу которого был построен замок* (Н. Степанов).

**P. S.** *Но ведь не скажешь "отражаться в зеркальной поверхности.*

> Здесь было совсем тихо, и наша «Испаньола», с развевающимся на ней черным флагом, отражалась в зеркальной поверхности воды (Р. Л. Стивенсон. [Остров сокровищ](https://books.google.ee/books?id=ONBMDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT122&lpg=PT122&dq=%D0%97%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%8C%20%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%85%D0%BE%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B9%20%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC%20%D1%84%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BC,%20%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%8C%20%D0%B2%20%D0%B7%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%85%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%20%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%8B.&source=bl&ots=5SeNtpbuue&sig=ACfU3U1uESW2WDFZ026WZXmi1GtBpeC3xw&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjN4YquiMXqAhXtk4sKHeZ_BCwQ6AEwDXoECAwQAQ#v=onepage&q=%D0%97%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%8C%20%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%85%D0%BE%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B9%20%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC%20%D1%84%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BC%2C%20%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%8C%20%D0%B2%20%D0%B7%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%85%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%20%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%8B.&f=false)).

А со словосочетанием "зеркало воды" вообще проблем нет — отражались в зеркале воды.

*Само озеро блестело на солнце, в чистом зеркале воды отражались деревья и листья* (Н. Якобсон). *Вершины берёз отражались в зеркале пруда* ([см.](https://rus5-vpr.sdamgia.ru/problem?id=259)).

**Дополнение** (после комментария)

> ...по спокойной, все еще розоватой в лучах солнца воде, среди **отраженных ею** облаков плавали лебеди, вопросительно и гордо изогнув шеи, а на берегах шумели ярко одетые дети, бросая птицам хлеб ([М. Горький. Жизнь Клима Самгина](https://studfile.net/preview/2959187/page:6/)).

Отражённый — страдательное причастие от глагола *отразить*.
[отрази́ться](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&ro=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F) (нсв. *отражаться*)
**2.** Дать своё отражение на гладкой, блестящей поверхности. *Отразиться **на** дне чайника. Луна отразилась **в** пруду. Отразиться **в** зеркале.*

Все три варианта возможны (мне, правда, ближе использование формы "ею", а не "ей").

Comment: Согласна с _V. V._ — вопрос и вправду интересен. А про какие три предлога Вы говорите? Обсуждались ведь только "в" и "на"

Comment: Да, вы правы, предлога два. Я имел ввиду три варианта.

Comment: Какой вывод:все три варианта допустимы?

Answer (score 1):

Как ни раздольно, как ни отрадно подчас бороздить по волнам, пусть и занимаясь нужным делом на плаву, как ни красивы отражения закатов и зорь ***на водной глади***, но все равно надо было возвращаться к берегу, к тому или иному, но к берегу. [Чингиз Айтматов. И дольше века длится день (Буранный полустанок) (1980-1984

Вскоре должна была наступить полная темнота повсюду, кроме дороги. И хотя на ней ни один фонарь еще не погас, их свет уже отражался ***на водной глади***. [Клайв Стейплз Льюис. Хроники Нарнии. Серебряное кресло (Г. А. Островская, 1991)]

Отражаться «в воде», но «на водной глади». «Гладь» подразумевает поверхность, с которыми после глагола «отражаться» употребляется предлог «на». Следовательно, «на ней».
Немного добавлю. Зеркало я не рассматривала, там всё ясно, как и с «зеркальными» сочетаниями. И, видимо, там, где автор хочет сравнить поверхность с зеркалом, предлог «в» употребим (см.второй ответ)

С употреблением «ей» вы справились сами и правильно растолковали.

Comment: V.V.:  _«Гладь» подразумевает поверхность, с которыми после глагола «отражаться» употребляется предлог «на»._ === Только ли "на"? А зеркало — разве не поверхность? Разве нельзя сказать "отражаться в зеркале"?

Comment: Но ведь не скажешь "отражаться в зеркальной поверхности".

Comment: _Аллазар: Но ведь не скажешь "отражаться в зеркальной поверхности"._ === А разве кто-то предлагал такое? А вот "отражение в (какой-либо) глади" — а почему бы и нет? См.  примеры: _Глядя на свое мутное **отражение в** фарфоровой **глади**, я задумался о невеселом будущем..._ [Юрий Нагибин. Война с черного хода (1990-1995)]; _Пруд просто необходим в небольших садиках, огороженных высокими стенами и изгородями, где отражение неба **в водной глади** избавляет от ощущения замкнутого пространства._ [ На берегу... // «Homes & Gardens», 2004.04.30]

Comment: _Аллазар: Но ведь не скажешь "отражаться в зеркальной поверхности"._ === См. примеры: https://www.google.com/search?q=отражаться+%22в+зеркальной+поверхности%22&client=safari&channel=ipad_bm&prmd=ivn&source=lnms&tbm=bks&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiCyaTph8XqAhUDy6YKHbPKB0MQ_AUoBnoECAwQBg&biw=768&bih=928&dpr=2

Comment: @slava1947, спасибо, согласна.

Comment: @Аллазар, хороший вопрос